# How to show up a calendar with XD datetimepicker when initial screen works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use XD DateTimePicker to show up a calendar, using a code as a reference at the link [DateTimePicker jQuery plugin select date and time](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) . The title is "Inline DateTimePicker Example ". But, although each buttons appeared, the calendar didn't work.

Here is the code I use of Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true
  } ;
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker3">
```

Here is a picture of current result of mine:

[image]

I will appreciate if you could tell me how to manage it.

Comment: We have not enough information to help you. Provide your HTML and your JS. If you can, create a JSFiddle or CodePen example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't have to use a "Q:" prefix in the title, everything you type after clicking the "Ask Question" button is assumed to be such.

Comment: I'm so sorry to bug you guys. I ended up expressing my current situation in codepen. Here is the thing. http://codepen.io/RYOHEI_1985/pen/rWdLXX

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class instead of a ID to select the calenedar. It should be

`$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ inline:true });`

An you need that ID included in your HTML markup, example:

`<html>
    <body>
      <div id="datetimepicker3"></div>
    </body>
</html>`

> Do not forget to include JQuery **before** the datetimepicker library

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I modify my code like what you pointed out. But, outcome didn't change. Thank you , though.

Comment: I've shared my code just now. please check it out if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @RyoheiDeIwata it seems to be a bug of the library. If you remove the `inline` option, it works properly, check out: http://codepen.io/mattiascaricato/pen/bBvgBW

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw what you made. My point is a calendar already showed up when screen initial screen opened. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

does it make any difference when you put it in a doc ready? Example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true
  } ;
});
```

I feel like youre trying to run code before it's ready, meaning it won't work correctly.

As others stated, a proper code preview would help too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I gave it a try of using what you stated. But, it didn't work. So, I ended up sharing my code now. I will be glad if you check it out and mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry to bug you guys. I ended up expressing my current situation in codepen. Here is the thing.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker3">
<script type="text/javascript" src="xd.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
format:'d.m.Y H:i',
inline:true
});
```

Can't I put a link of codepen in this textarea? I was trying , but it couldn't. So, I wrote down my code directory.